# SP how can I sum the amount of all leftchild in parentid

Tags: mysql

I have this data and table structure,I am creating MySQL stored procedure to sum all the amount in the leftchild of the parentid, I don't have enough knowledge in stored procedure.and I need some help please because I'm lost.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytree` (
  `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `memberid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `mytree` (`parentid`, `memberid`, `position`, `amount`) VALUES
    (8, 27, 'R', 0.00),
    (8, 28, 'L', 0.00),
    (24, 26, 'R', 0.00),
    (0, 1, '', 5500.00),
    (24, 25, 'L', 0.00),
    (21, 24, 'L', 500.00),
    (21, 23, 'R', 0.00),
    (18, 20, 'R', 1500.00),
    (18, 19, 'L', 0.00),
    (15, 18, 'R', 2000.00),
    (15, 17, 'L', 0.00),
    (13, 16, 'L', 0.00),
    (13, 15, 'R', 2500.00),
    (12, 14, 'R', 0.00),
    (12, 13, 'L', 3000.00),
    (10, 12, 'R', 3500.00),
    (10, 11, 'L', 0.00),
    (7, 10, 'R', 4000.00),
    (7, 9, 'L', 0.00),
    (5, 8, 'R', 500.00),
    (5, 7, 'L', 4500.00),
    (1, 6, 'R', 0.00),
    (1, 5, 'L', 5500.00),
    (20, 22, 'R', 0.00),
    (20, 21, 'L', 1000.00);
```

here is my **stored proc**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `count_left_right_amount`(IN `p_memid` INT, OUT `tot_left_amount` DECIMAL(10,2))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

DECLARE row_total decimal(10,2);
DECLARE total decimal(10,2);
DECLARE m_left int;
DECLARE run_left int;
DECLARE p_id int;

set total =  0;

select memberid into p_id from mytree where position = 'L' AND parentid = p_memid;




WHILE  p_id != 0 DO

 select sum(amount) into row_total from mytree where parentid = p_id 
  GROUP BY parentid;

 select memberid into m_left from mytree where parentid = p_id;
 set total = total + row_total;
 set tot_left_amount = total;
 set p_id = m_left;


END WHILE;


END
```

Example if the parentid is 5 ,so the leftchild is 7 then go down to his subtree sum it all,so the total amount in the left child is '22500'? please correct me if I'm wrong.

please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You must assign tot_left_amount (the OUT parameter) something at the end of your procedure. Furthermore, the logic in your loop does not appear right, you need to sum the amount for the children somehow.

Comment: @Lennart,I edit now,yes I'm lost in my logic to sum the amount in my while loop.can you help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following:

```
alter table mytree add constraint ck1tree unique (memberid);
alter table mytree add constraint ck2tree unique (parentid,position);
```

One suggestion is to start with a procedure that calculates the sum of the subtree (regardless of position):

There is probably more elegant solutions to this, but I'm in a bit of a hurry and I think it will get you started so I'll post anyhow. Note that you will probably have to adjust the variable @@max_sp_recursion_depth;

```
set @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 10;
delimiter $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE sum_subtree
    (IN `p_memid` INT, OUT `tot_left_amount` DECIMAL(10,2)  
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE tmp decimal(10,2) default 0;
    DECLARE tmp2 decimal(10,2) default 0;
    DECLARE a decimal(10,2);
    DECLARE mid int;
    DECLARE finished int default 0;

    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
        select memberid, amount
        from mytree where parentid = p_memid;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN c1;
    get_amount: LOOP
        FETCH c1 into mid, a;
        IF finished = 1 THEN
            LEAVE get_amount;
        END IF;

        -- recursive call to procedure 
        CALL sum_subtree(mid, tmp);
        SET tmp2 = tmp2 + tmp + a;
    END LOOP;
    SET tot_left_amount = tmp2;
END $$
delimiter ;


call sum_subtree(7,@x);
select @x;
+----------+
| @x       |
+----------+
| 18000.00 |
+----------+
```

Now you can create a procedure that select the value from the 'L' branch, call this procedure and return the sum of those two values. Hope it helps

Edit: example of calling procedure:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `count_left_right_amount`(
    IN `p_memid` INT, OUT `tot_left_amount` DECIMAL(10,2)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    DECLARE a decimal(10,2);
    DECLARE m int;
    DECLARE s decimal(10,2);

    select memberid, amount into m, a from mytree
    where parentid = p_memid and position = 'L';

    call sum_subtree(m,s);
    set tot_left_amount = a + s;
END $$
delimiter ;


call count_left_right_amount(5,@y);

MariaDB [test]> select @y;
+----------+
| @y       |
+----------+
| 22500.00 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: first of all thank you so much I give a try on this,can I ask,is it necessary to declare this set @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 10; in my stored proc ?.Thank you in advance

Comment: It does not belong to the procedure, the call to the sp will cause an error `ERROR 1456 (HY000): Recursive limit 1 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine sum_subtree` if set too low. My interpretation is that it limits the height of the call stack for the procedure.

Comment: ,Thank you for the quick reply...Okay I'm still stuck on how to compute the amount of the left subtree which is 7 if I call sum_subtree(5,@x);

Comment: I've added an example, see if it helps

Comment: I get error where to put this set @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 10; ?inside the begin ?

Comment: No, it does not belong to the procedure. It is a global variable that limits the amount of recursive calls that a procedure can do. You can create the procedures first, if you try to execute the call to the procedure you might get an error. Now, `set @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 10;` and execute the call once again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19748/discussion-between-ashton-and-lennart).

Comment: I could not run the set @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 10; I'm using MySQL database

Comment: ,you said it's not part of stored procedure,so where should I run this  set @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 10 ? please help I'm really confuse how to make this work

Comment: ,please help I really could not run the SP that you give

Comment: It's a server system variable, google for @@max_sp_recursion_depth AND mysql

Comment: ,just want to ask question,if you limit the recursion to 10 ? what if the subtree is long then the sp is called only 10 times,then I could not get anymore the correct amount in my left children ?am I right ?please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: That's correct, you will get an error if the depth of your search tree is greater than @@max_sp_recursion_depth.

Comment: someon suggested in stackoverflow  "using an INOUT variable for the return_result." on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315343/mysql-stored-procedure-recursive

Comment: Thank you also for putting index to my table. I appreciated it. :)